# Como usar o "echo" em uma view do Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, mvc, laravel-blade

Estou querendo que no meu `layout` `blade` **`echo`** somente se a variável `$errors` estiver definida:

```
@section('mensagens')
    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        {{ isset($errors) ? 
            '<div class="col-md-8 alert alert-danger">'
              $errors->first('prontuario')
              $errors->first('senha')
            '</div>'
            :
            ''
        }}

        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    @show
```

Como eu faço para ele só mostrar essa `div` da classe `alert-danger` se a variável `$errors` do meu formulário estiver definida?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você também pode fazer assim:

```
@section('mensagens')
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        @if (count($errors))
            <div class="col-md-8 alert alert-danger">
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    {{ $error }}
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @endif
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
@show
```

Em vez de você setar cada erro individual, você percorre todos os erros e exibe cada um.

Comment: Deu certo!!! Ficou exatamente do jeito que eu queria, só aparecendo a div quando tiver o erro. Obrigado!

Comment: Por nada! 
Estamos aqui para ajudar uns aos outros! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `@if` e `@endif`

```
@section('mensagens')
    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="row"> 
      @if($errors)
          <div class="col-md-2"></div>
              <div class="col-md-8 alert alert-danger">
                  {{ $errors->first('prontuario') }}
                  {{ $errors->first('senha') }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2"></div>
          </div>
      @endif
    </div>
@show
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas mesmo não estando definida a variável $errors, ainda aparece o pequeno retângulo da div :/

Comment: Vai subindo o IF...

Comment: Não está indo. Ainda aparece a DIV alert mesmo subindo. Estou pensando em fazer essa parte em PHP...

Comment: Posta seu Controller onde está essa variável.

Comment: if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('/')
                ->withErrors($validator) // envia de volta todos os erros para o form
                ->withInput(Input::except('senha'));
        }